# Negative balance effect credit score

Tags: india, credit-score, bank-account

I have an saving account in Oriental Bank. I am not using this account for last 1.5 year. Currently the balance is negative.

I am staying in Bihar since last two year. It is not possible to go Delhi account home branch and close account.

Please suggest what to do. It may affect my credit score.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the local branch and complete the formalities, pay the charges and close the account.

It can also be done remotely by writing a registered letter to the Delhi branch.